# Qt start an external program in Qt gridLayout

Tags: linux, qt, qgridlayout

I was wondering, is it possible to start an external program via Qt and display the program in Qt gridLayout (or inside Qt window)?

At the moment, I'm able to start an external program via Qt, but I haven't find a way to display the program inside the QtWindow. In other words, the program just appear outside Qt window.

```
Qt Pro file
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-09-21T16:31:30
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = WifiProject
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Main window .h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkConfigurationManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkSession>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkInterface>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QList>

#include <QProcess>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QBoxLayout>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_StartWicd_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    void searchForNetwork();
    QProcess *wicdProgram;

    void addWicdProgram();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QWindow>


QString program = "/usr/bin/wicd-gtk";

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    searchForNetwork();
    addWicdProgram();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::searchForNetwork(){

}

void MainWindow::addWicdProgram(){
    wicdProgram = new QProcess(this);
    wicdProgram->setProgram(program);


    WId winid = this->winId();
    QWindow *container = QWindow::fromWinId(winid);
    QWidget *program_start = createWindowContainer(container);
    setCentralWidget(program_start);


    ui->wifiGridLayout->addWidget(program_start);
    wicdProgram->start();


    qDebug()<<"wicd addded";
    //ui->wifiGridLayout->addWidget(program_start);
}

void MainWindow::on_StartWicd_clicked()
{
    //wicdProgram->start(program);
    qDebug()<<"the wicd should have started";
    wicdProgram->terminate();


}
```

Comment: On Linux you can use `QX11EmbedContainer` for that.

Comment: Hi hank Thank you for your replay, I did some research about the QX11EmbedContainer (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qx11embedcontainer.html#details), but when i implemented the code Qt gives me an error(QX11EmbedContainer does not name a type).

I code in qt in Raspberry Pi and the compiler is G++.

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using?  For Qt5 `QX11EmbedContainer` has been replaced by [`QWidget::createWindowContainer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer).

Comment: Hi G.M, 
I have look into QWidget::createWindowContainer as you have suggested.
However, the program still start outside the my QGridLayout. :(

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the relevant code?

Comment: Hi GM, I have posted the relevant code.... 
could you please help me in figuring out what i did wrong..? :D

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to retrieve the window id of the application launch by qt and you can do like this :

```
QWindow *window = QWindow::fromWinId("Id of the application");
window->setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window);
```

Comment: How could I retrieve the Window Id of the application?